Is there a way to get suction cups be reliable for decorations?
I am trying to hang some Halloween decorations I bought last year. They are dependent on plastic suction cups to hold them on glass, but a couple of them keep falling off.
When preparing the glass, we gave it a thorough cleaning with glass cleaner and I also wiped the backs of the cups to make sure they were also clean. Out of 8, 2 just don't want to stay on.
Is there more we can do to get these to stay on?



if you grease them, the grease will act as additional air sealant

Or use a tiny dab of liquid detergent, perhaps mixed with water. N.B.: if left in place too long, it may be difficult to remove the rings on glass left under the suction cups.

A tiny dab of any liquid. Something that evaporates very slowly will work best, I use oil.

If you use water it will evaporate and break the seal, oil/grease won't.  Obvs you'll have to clean the glass after you remove the sucker.
